# A word for describing thinking of something as better

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the action of looking or thinking about someone, and taking them as better than the subject is.

For example,

> I think you ______ him too much, he isn't really that good at math!

I thought about the word *"overestimate"*, but its connotation is that thinking of the object as better is wrong (unjustly assuming that the object is better). I'm looking for a word that can fit into that sentence also (for example).

> Of course I ______ her. She's my teacher, and I think she's very wise!

Is there a word or a phrase to describe that?

*Edit for clarification*: I'm looking for a word that can serve as the word *'overrate'* in the first example, and as the word *'commend'* in the second example.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47227/discussion-on-question-by-yotam-salmon-a-word-for-describing-thinking-of-somethi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about *admire*, *esteem*, or *respect*?

> I think you *admire*, *esteem*, or *respect* him too much, he isn't
>   really that good at math!
>
> Of course I *admire*, *esteem*, or *respect* her. She's my teacher,
>   and I think she's very wise!

From M-W:

> *admire*: to feel respect or approval for (someone or something)
>
> *esteem*: to think very highly or favorably of (someone or something)
>
> *respect*: a feeling of admiring someone or something that is good, valuable, important, etc.